# Pattern matching for lambdas?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

Is it possible to have pattern matching of arguments and casing for an anonymous function? If so, what is the syntax?

Ipsum lorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly the same as for named functions:

```
- (fn 0 => 1 | x => 34) 1;
val it = 34 : int

- (fn (_::y::_) => y) [1,2,3];
val it = 2 : int
```

(A warning was omitted in the second example.)